# Object vs Extend in Java

Tags: java, object, extends

I may be wrong as I have not got too much experience with Java, but here is a question.

I have a class which contains many methods (basically it is a simple library).

I create an object of this class let's say `MyLibrary obj = new MyLibrary(parameters);`

The parameters set up any necessary functionality for the library to run correctly.

Then I can call `obj.getSomething`/`obj.setSomething`/`obj.createSomething` etc etc...

In my main class I really need only one this kind of library object.

Now... Would it be more useful for me not to use it as an object, but put it as `extends` and then create a function inside of the library like a constructor which I would call manually?

---

**EDIT:**

The relation between the one class and MyLibrary is very close. Basically, I have many classes which do similar things but have some different higher layer functionality. So I separated method which **must** be in all those classes.

It seems it is very similar to `shape` class and `triangle`, `circle`, `square` example. So `MyLibrary` is similar to `shape` which contains all the foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you described strongly resembles a *utility class*, similar to Java's [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). The class has only `static` methods, and a private constructor to prevent instantiations. This is a well-known idiomatic pattern in Java - you can use it to create your own groups of methods providing related functionality.

You should not extend, or even instantiate, utility classes at all. Starting with Java-5, you can statically import them so that you could use their methods without making an explicit reference to their class.

Answer (score 3):

`extends` is used when you need an inheritance hierarchy.  It seems more logical to put your code in two separate classes here, like you have it now.

Also, if your "library class" does multiple unrelated things, it should probably be split into multiple classes - one for each task.

Answer (score 3):

You should really only use `extends` when you have a *is-a* relationship. So, you can think, **is** my main class a MyLibrary or should my class **have** a MyLibrary.

From your described problem, it sounds like having MyLibrary is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited detail that you have provided, you might want to consider the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

`extends` should only be used when one object needs to inherit the characteristics and functionality of another one because they are very closely related. For example, if you have a `Shape` class, then you would extend `Shape` to create `Circle`, `Square`, and `Triangle`. Before you use `extends` you should learn more about inheritence and when you should and should not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a `static` class to use. Similiar to javas MATH class [API for math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). You can just use the methods of the class without making an object of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well If your class if performing utility functions then you should mark all methods as `static` and use operations like

```
MyLibrary.doSomething();
MyLibrary.createSomething();
MyLibrary.getSomething();
```

But this wont allow you to keep some data members in the class and if you keep them they will be static as well.

I don't think so that `extends` suits your case.

Also if you want to keep only an object then you should look at `Singleton` A class for which only one instance can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just using `MyLibrary` and may not alter it, you should use a wrapper that makes the whole thing a Singleton, as already proposed by [Code-Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691200/792725).

```
public class MyLibraryWrapper {
    private static MyLibrary instance = null;

    private MyLibraryWrapper() {}

    public static MyLibrary getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MyLibrary();
        return instance;
```

So in your code you would use

```
MyLibraryWrapper.getInstance().getSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create singleton in java 1.5 or above is to use ENUM.

```
public enum Test { 
    INSTANCE;
}
```

INSTANCE is the only instance of Test class.