# Which pattern am I looking for?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Say I have the following interface:

```
ICarProvider
```

And the following classes implementing it:

```
RedCarProvider:ICarProvider
BlueCarProvider:ICarProvider
GreenCarProvider:ICarProvider
```

Now, what I would like to do is this:

Depending on the settings of the user, create a single instance of one (only one) of these classes and use that throughout the entire session of the application. So my logic should only know the interface and where to get the instance.

Is there a pattern for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Comment: You should call it abstract factory pattern since there are two patterns: `Abstract factory` and `factory method`.

Comment: The basic idea is identical, the difference is in how the factory is called.

Comment: no. It's more than that. Abstract factory is used to define how a factory should look like, and it's whole purpose of the factory implementations is to create objects, while factory method is most often used to create aggregates to the class that it's defined in.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton Factory

http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/Singleton_Factory_patterns_example

[Singleton Factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356004/singleton-factory-method)

[Creating singleton factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355899/creating-singleton-factory)

Answer (score 3):

Abstract Factory pattern. Read more on [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

> > In software development, a factory is the location in the code at which objects are constructed. The intent in employing the pattern is to insulate the creation of objects from their usage. This allows for new derived types to be introduced with no change to the code that uses the base class.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the some sort of factory pattern.

I can't refrain myself from being sceptical about the need for a pattern to describe something so trivial.

Comment: ...and yet one exists. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

That what you have presented seems to be a factory patter, but you should not create a class only for describing the properties of an object, sometime is better to use an map for those.